# reading and writing UTF16 file using fstream in c++

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm not familiar with c++ stream things. so I practice stream input, output. 
of course, fstream as well.

It's not problem to read and write a file encoded on mutibyte character based encoding, but 
I got stuck when wide character like utf16.

here is my code and test file.

```
vector<wstring> strings;
wifstream ifs(L"inputtxt/utf16.txt", std::wifstream::binary | std::wifstream::in);
wchar_t buff[1024] = {0,};
while (!ifs.fail()){
  ifs.getline(buff, 1024);
  wstring str(buff);
  strings.push_back(str);
}
ifs.close();

wofstream ofs(L"outputtxt/utf16.txt", std::wofstream::out | std::wifstream::binary);
vector<wstring>::iterator it = strings.begin();
for (; it != strings.end(); it++ ) {
  ofs.write(it->c_str(), it->length());
  ofs.put(L'\n');
}
ofs.close();
```

this is a test file encoded in utf16.

```
what are you doing? 
what are you doing?
```

what's the problem? and how can I do this correctly?

plz give me a tip. thanks.

Comment: `what's the problem?` --> This important fact is missing from your question. We can't help you if you son't say what is not working.

Comment: Note: `wchar_t` is a weird beast, whose bit-width depends on the compiler/platform you are using; in C++11, prefer the explicit `char16_t` for UTF-16 at least you'll know it's exactly 16-bits.